# WPF to PDF with a different layout

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, layout

I'm looking for a way to print data which a user of the C#/WPF program has entered.
The problem is the layout difference of the screen compaired to the pdf.

The program layout is made for a display (landscape view) which is different from the pdf file layout (portret view).

Here is a printscreen of grid with labels, textboxes, radiobuttons and checkboxes:

[image: printscreen of grid with labels, textboxes, radiobuttons and checkboxes]
as it is shown in the application.
All the labels, textboxes, radiobuttons and checkboxes are drawn on a grid.

Here is a printscreen of how the pdf should look like.

[image: PDF portret view example]

So I'm not just looking for a way to copy the grid to PDF but to change the layout also.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. Rework your UI so that it more fluid and can work at (almost) any resolution or screen ratio so you can just render the view directly. If you use a WrapPanel (for example) then the controls will be laid out to fit automatically much like your screenshot shows.
2. If that's not possible, you could create a "print view" which will have the controls laid out in portrait mode rather than landscape mode. This will bind to the same view model as the regular view so all the data will be correct. You can then render that view in the Print command. This view is defined in the same way as the "normal" view but when you print you use that view rather than the "normal" view.

If you put each question and answer(s) in a grid or stack panel then you can lay out the questions something like this:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel x:Name="Question1">
        ... Controls for question 1
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Question2">
        ... Controls for question 2
    </StackPanel>
    ...
</WrapPanel>
```

This will lay the page out in columns, with the height being the available vertical space.

If you change to "Horizontal" you'll get the questions laid out in rows.

Comment: Dear ChrisF, I'm new to WPF so I really can use your help. Can you give me a small example how to create the "print view" which will have the controls laid out in portrait mode which is bound to the regular view and how to render that view in the "print command"?

Comment: @MathiasF given your actual page, I'd go for `Wrap Panel`. That way the view will sort itself out when rendered with the print dimensions.

Comment: how should I do this? Should I put each question with Answer in a wrappanel and all those wrappanels in antoher wrappanel? How can I retain the spaces between questions using wrappanel? How can I keep the Question-number before the Question and Answers using wrappanel?

Comment: Put each each question and answers in a vertical stack panel or grid then put those in the wrap panel.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF, I'm going to try it. Can you still give me an example how to create a 'print view' which will have the controls laid out in portrait mode which is bound to the regular view and how I can render it? Even if it's not the best solution I'd still like to try it.

Comment: Putting the questions in a Wrappanel works but I'm still limited to the wrappanel. Lets say I have 40 questions. On the screen I can show 10 questions at the same time so I need 4 wrappanels. On a pdf document A4 page I can print 14 questions so 3 pages could show all the questions. Is there a way to print the 4 screens to 3 pages?